# Why doesn't Oracle recognize a stored generated column definition?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, calculated-columns

I have the following generated column defined within a `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
NET_ROWS_ADDED NUMBER(18) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ROW_COUNT - PREV_ROW_COUNT) /*STORED*/,
```

`ROW_COUNT` and `PREV_ROW_COUNT` are simple `NUMBER(18)` columns previously defined in the same table.

Everything works fine as it's written.
But if I un-comment the `STORED` option, I get:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I need to convert this into a `STORED` generated column.
What is wrong with the syntax here? It all looks correct to me ...

Comment: There is no `STORED` option in Oracle, are you using MySQL?

Comment: You get the error because STORED is invalid; Oracle never stores virtual columns. Don't know why you think you need to; you don't, see [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1). You can still index then, use in where clauses, create views, ... in short anything you do with a stored column. Except Set their value directly.

Comment: lol I keep looking at MySQL documentation by accident. That explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Oracle** doesn't store a virtual column on disk, it is only evaluate on demand. You are probably confused with the **STORED** option in **MySQL**. Since there is no `STORED` clause in Oracle, it throws a syntax error.

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm):

> **GENERATED ALWAYS**
>
> The optional keywords GENERATED ALWAYS are provided for semantic
> clarity. They indicate that the column is not stored on disk, but is
> evaluated on demand.
>
> **VIRTUAL**
>
> The optional keyword VIRTUAL is provided for semantic
> clarity.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly the problem. I keep accidentally looking at MySQL documentation, when I'm looking for Oracle stuff.

Comment: Sometimes my googling brings me to the MySQL pages too, drives me nuts - don't beat yourself up about it

Answer (score 0):

There is an overview of which products supports `stored` (and other storage options) at [modern-sql.com](https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/generated-always-as#storage). Pictured: support for the `stored` options as of late 2022.

[image]